# Why is my PDO Mysql database connection closing slow?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a PDO connection to a MySQL database. Making the connection is lightening fast. Subsequently I run a very complicated query 1 (using temp tables, SELECT, INSERT and other operations all subsequently) which runs extremely fast (around 0.1 second). I know this query 1 is successfully executed every time.

Much further in the code I am opening a new PDO connection to do a simple SELECT statement. This SELECT statement seemed not to be fetching any results (it will only fetch results if the complicated query 1 is successfully finished).

As I opened a connection earlier to execute the complicated query 1 I thought I would have to close that one first. I added the below code to unset the connection. This helped. However, I can see now that it takes a few minutes to run only the piece of code: unset($stmt);

> $stmt = $pdo->prepare($QUERY);
>
> $stmt->execute();
>
> unset($stmt);
>
> unset($pdo);

Could it be that my complicated query is running in the background while I think it is finished, but it actually isn't?

My question is: Why does executing this code: unset($stmt); take so extremely long?

Comment: How do you know `unset($stmt)` is what's running slow and not `$stmt->execute()`?

Comment: @Robbert Because I measured it exactly around unset($stmt);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query I was executing simply took too long and was still running on the background while the php parser continued.